# How can I cut a window sill bevel on a 10" table saw?

Tags: windows, woodworking, replacement

I need to cut a 10 degree slope 4 7/8 long on a 2x6 board.  The sill will be 33” long.  Can I do this on a table saw with a 10” blade?

Comment: You won't get 4-7/8" of cut depth from a 10" blade. You'd be lucky to even get 4". Could be done in 2 cuts though - one from each side - if you're careful to line it up on the 2nd cut.

Comment: I doubt it with a single cut.  Full raise of the blade be around 4 inches or less.

Comment: @brhans is right. Make a taller auxiliary fence to improve accuracy.

Comment: A bandsaw would do the trick. Also, head over to [woodworking.se] for some woodworking expertise and suggestions on how to make this happen.

Comment: Also, I edited the title question to more accurately reflect what _I think_ you're asking. Feel free to [edit] to change if necessary

Comment: Yould you post a drawing of the desired outcome with dimensions? It isn't completely clear whether you are trying to machine the drip edge or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Most 10" table saws will do good to get 3" to 3-1/2" depth of cut at 90°. Once you start leaning the blade over for a bevel, you're going to get less depth of cut.

You're looking for a 4-7/8" depth of cut at the bevel, so you'd need to tip your blade until you reach your desired bevel *or* you're at a 2-7/16" depth of cut, whichever comes first.

Once you've got the bevel set, mark your cut line on both your final work piece and a test piece of sill material. Make a cut into the scrap piece (to ensure you're lined up correctly) and set it aside. Then make your first pass on your work piece, cutting as deep as you can get on this pass.

You'll need to then reset the fence to make the cut from the other end of the board. Use the line marked on the test piece to get this lined up by ensuring your fence is the proper distance away from the blade so that the cut lines up exactly. Once you've got this lined up, run your work piece through.

If you can't make the full cut at the desired bevel in two passes, you'll either have to live with a different slope for this sill (which may not be catastrophic, depending on where this sill is in relation to other windows), *or* max out your depth of cut from both sides (as outlined above) then finish the cut with a hand saw, oscillating multi-tool, or other cutting instrument available to you.

Having used a couple of Japanese-style pull saws, I will say that a rip cut on the small amount of wood that will be remaining will go *very* quickly. If you do any other woodworking at all, this would be a good investment. Even if you don't you can get them on the big river's retail website for very little money.

---

An option that *doesn't* involve your table saw would be to find a friend, neighbor, local woodworker or maker space that has a band saw. A band saw will make quick work of this resawing operation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the width you need versus the width of board you have *and* whether the underside can be sloped, you might nip your bevel off the front and back of the board and have the ‘flat’ of the board be set at a 10° tilt.

Comment: This works, but then you still have to have some sort of beveled support to hold the otherwise flat piece at the proper angle.

Comment: Agree, @FreeMan. I just happen to have two very handy wedges cut at 10°, that are exactly the width of the sill and probably 1-1/2” wide. In seriousness, though, you can also easily cut a flat on the underside with the tablesaw. You’ll get 3” depth easily and it doesn’t have to look nice.